# Ember.js - Learning dynamic segments, link-to, nested routes

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to learn how to do dynamic segments in Ember. I thought I understood but obviously it's not working.
Are my corresponding file structure and model queries correct?

**router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('photos', function() {
    this.route('photo', { path: '/:photo_id' }, function() {
      this.route('comments');
      this.route('comment', { path: '/comments/:comment_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

Creating dynamic link list somewhere in the app using the photos model:

```
{{#each photos as |photo|}}
  {{#link-to 'photos.photo' photo}}{{photo.name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

Does everything line up with my file stucture?

**File structure:**

```
app
├── controllers
|   └── photo
|   |   └── comment
|   |   |   └── index.js
|   |   ├── index.js
|   |   └── comments.js
|   └── photos.js
├── routes
|   └── photo
|   |   └── comment
|   |   |   └── index.js
|   |   ├── index.js
|   |   └── comments.js
|   └── photos.js
└── templates
|   └── photo
|   |   └── comment
|   |   |   └── index.hbs
|   |   ├── index.hbs
|   |   └── comments.hbs
|   └── photos.hbs
└── router.js
```

**routes/photos.js**

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('photo');
}
```

Lets say I want to display all the photos with comments, I can get the model below.

**routes/photo/index.js**

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('photo', params.photo_id, {include: 'comments'});
}
```

Unsure about the next 2 models.

**routes/photo/comments.js**

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.query('comment', { photo: photo_id })
}
```

**routes/photo/comment/index.js**

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('comment', params.comment_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File sturcture should reflect what is in router.js file. I just shown only routes hierarchy and it's applicable to controllers and templates.

app/routes/photos.js
app/routes/photos/index.js
app/routes/photos/photo.js
app/routes/photos/photo/comments.js

You are missing `photos` folder. refer this [alexspeller diagonal](http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/route/photos.photo?routesInput=this.route(%27photos%27%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.route(%27photo%27%2C%20%7B%20path%3A%20%27%2F%3Aphoto_id%27%20%7D%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.route(%27comments%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.route(%27comment%27%2C%20%7B%20path%3A%20%27%2Fcomments%2F%3Acomment_id%27%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: That code is amazing and would have solved all my problems. Thanks!

Comment: Code is written by AlexSpeller who is doing stellar work in ember slack community.